# SQL 2008 Compression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, compression, char, varchar

I am an intern and was asked to do some research on SQL 2008 data compression. We want to store several parts of outlook emails in a table. The problem is that we want to store the entire email body in a field, but then want to compress it. Using Char() will not store the whole body, but will allow compression... using varchar() will store the entire body but not allow compression. Any ideas on how to store the whole body AND compress it?

Thank You for your replies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Types of data compression in SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2007/11/12/types-of-data-compression-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

[Creating Compressed Tables and Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx)

[Whitepaper: Data Compression: Strategy, Capacity Planning and Best Practices](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/comments/850.aspx)

Comment: wow thanks Mitch, looks like I have a lot of catching up on SQL 2008 functionality great to see this feature is in there

Answer (score 3):

SQL 2008 can do this for you, see [Creating Compressed Tables and Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the maximum possible size of your row exceeds the maximum allowable row size?  You mentioned 7,500+ character emails so it sounds like you're getting close to the limit.

> "A table cannot be enabled for compression when the maximum row size plus the compression overhead exceeds the maximum row size of 8060 bytes."

from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx